# Cloud functions with firebase: firebase.functions is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After creating a cloud function `addMessage` on Firebase using Firebase SDK 4.12.0, the following code does not work when attempting to call the `addMessage` function from within my client app:

```
var firebase = require("../node_modules/firebase")
var functions = firebase.functions();

functions.httpsCallable("addMessage").call(
    //...
)
```

**TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function**

Answer (score 21):

The solution was to add
`require("firebase/functions")`

Comment: a "-" not / is seems const functions = require('firebase-functions');

Comment: For those who are loading from CDN, include corresponding Firebase JS SDKs. For example, if firebase.functions() is undefined, then include  `firebase-functions.js` from CDN as documented here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries_CDN

Comment: If using ES6 use this: import 'firebase/functions'