# TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase

I know someone else has [posted this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480761/cloud-functions-with-firebase-firebase-functions-is-not-a-function), but I believe mine has a right declaration and still doesn't work:

**Running the sendEmail.js:**

```
node sendEmail.js
```

**Inside sendEmail.js:**

```
"use strict";
// Initialize Function Caller App
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/functions");

var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "my-project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://my-project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "my-project-id",
  storageBucket: "my-project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var functions = firebase.functions(); // Error here: TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function
```

I got the above sample from the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). It works for my other project but not the current one. I've also run the following in my `sendEmail.js` folder:

```
npm install firebase@5.10.1 --save
```

In my Firebase project root folder, my `package.json` file has the `firebase-functions` dependency too:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.0"
  },
```

But FYI, my `sendEmail.js` is in the following folder:

```
project-root\testing\sendEmail.js
project-root\testing\node_modules\@firebase
project-root\testing\node_modules\@firebase\functions
```

And I still get this error:

```
var functions = firebase.functions();
                         ^
TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\project-root\testing\sendEmail.js:17:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

May I know what else do I need to check? Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add into the HTML file that includes your javascript the following import line:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/<version>/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```