# Firebase: How to call an https.onCall function node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

According to Firebase's documentation, the following code can be used to call a onCall function named **addMessage**.

```
var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
})
```

I have a function named **test**, with the following code in Javascript (just to test this functionality):

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log(data);
  data.page++;
  console.log(data);

  var testing = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');

  while(data.page < 5) {
    testing({page: data.page}).then(res => {
    console.log("done");
    })
  }
});
```

When running this, however, I get the following error:

> Unhandled error TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883213/typeerror-firebase-functions-is-not-a-function

Comment: Here's a similar question for you to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480761/cloud-functions-with-firebase-firebase-functions-is-not-a-function

Comment: @TravisWebb That is not a duplicate. The error may be the same, but the question you linked is trying to run a node script in the browser. OP here is trying to **call** a Cloud Function from within the browser, in which case they need to include the client-side `firebase-functions` SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firebase.functions()` method comes from `firebase/functions` package, not from `firebase` or `firebase-functions`.

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/functions');
const firebaseConfig = {<YOUR_CONFIG_HERE>};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = app.functions();
```

Comment: I did exactly this now, but when deploying I get the error **TypeError: app.functions is not a function**

Comment: So my issue ended up being something with npm. I deleted my package-lock.json and node_modules folder and reinstalled everything. After that, your answer worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not be including the client-side Cloud Functions SDK into your web app. Depending on how you include the other Firebase SDKs, you might need to do [what Phani linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480761/cloud-functions-with-firebase-firebase-functions-is-not-a-function), or include it in another (e.g. `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-functions.js"></script>`).

The process is covered in the documentation on [setting up your client development environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment).

Comment: I have included both firebase and firebase-functions as follows:

`const firebase = require("firebase");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');`

I've also tried `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');`
As well as `functions.httpsCallable('test');`

Always the same error.

Comment: I should also mention that this code is all inside my index.js file in the functions directory of the firebase project. As far as I know, this is not a "web-app" or anything, it's just the functions of the project in node.js.

Comment: If you're trying to call one firebase function from another one, you're probably over complicating things.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787159/3399890

Comment: @robsiemb I have the same issue. If you want to implement your system following a microservices approach, the general idea is to divide the system into services and expose an API. In my case, I also don't want all the APIs to de directly usable by client and must connect them through an intermediary service. In such cases, I need to use an HTTPS callable trigger. So, can this be done by using the web SDK from Nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scripts definitions to app.js

```
scriptInit = (scrName) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = scrName;
    script.async = false;
    script.type="module"

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.scriptInit("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js");
    this.scriptInit("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-functions.js");
}
```

for function call the following worked:

```
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
const functions = require("firebase/functions");
const firebaseConfig = {FIREBASE_CONFIG};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const functionsFB = functions.getFunctions(app);

return (async () => {
let fbSomeFuncName =  (functions.httpsCallable(functionsFB, 'somefunction'))
            let data = await fbSomeFuncName().then(data=>{return (data.data)}).catch(err=>{console.log("error:"+err)})
return data
// don't forget to add data to the response
```