# Firebase Functions Error - firebase.functions is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am importing all the correct parts, but am getting an error that functions doesn't exist in firebase.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

When I call:

```
firebaseConfig = {My App details};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
db = firebase.firestore();
functions = firebase.functions();
```

The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function`

Comment: Can you mention the error

Comment: The complete error

Comment: @Tessaracter The error is `Uncaught TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

This type of error has very similar others that might occur on calling Firestore functions. For your error specifically, it seems that to fix your error you need to add `require("firebase/functions")` - as per the question [Cloud functions with firebase: firebase.functions is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480761/cloud-functions-with-firebase-firebase-functions-is-not-a-function) on the Community.

Let me know if the information helped you!